# Select an item from dropdown in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, primefaces, selenium-webdriver

I want to select an item from a dropdown using selenium. The project uses jsf, primefaces, spring. The dropdown html appears in a list.
Like.

```
<div id="mydropdown">
   <ul>
      <li>03<li>
      <li>04</li>
      <li>23</li>
      <li>24</li>
      <li>30</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Since i want to select a random value inside of hardcoding the nth <li> to be selected, I wrote the code as

```
String selectItem ="03";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul/li[contains(.,'"+selectItem+"')])"));
```

But the output is:

```
[ <li>03<li>,
  <li>23</li>,
  <li>30</li> ]
```

It selects all <li> items containing 3. I does not consider the zero before the 3.

My Question is: How do get the output like `[ <li> 03 </li> ]` only?

Comment: You have an unbalanced closing round-bracket. Is that typo?

Comment: yes. it is a typo. i will correct it..thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for an exact match:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul/li[.='" + selectItem + "']"));
```

Comment: thank you ..it also works with driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul/li[text()='" + selectItem + "']"));

Answer (score -3):

```
Select oSelection = new Select(driver.findElement(By.locator("YOURDROPDOWNLOCATOR")));

oSelection.selectByVisibleText("YOURDESIREDCHOICE");
```

Comment: Using a `Select` object works only on HTML `select` elements. The OP's HTML uses `ul`.